# First Array Item in ObservableArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I am trying to populate a cascading select2 drop-downs using knockoutJS. 
The code appears to be working fine when making use of static data like in the `function staticbuildData()`, but throws an error when using the function `function buildData()`.

The first drop-down populates the data properly however, upon selection of an item in the first drop-down the following error is thrown:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childOptions' of null

It turns out that the following line is unable to find a child option and returning null:

```
 var make = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.togaMakers,function(item)
```

The only thing I can think of is that `staticbuildData()` is returning an array, whereas `buildData()` is returning an observableArray, and hence not finding the correct child option.

Am I on the right track or does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening?

**Knockout**

```
var viewModel = {
    togaMakers: buildData(),
    // togaMakers: staticbuildData(),
    selectedInstitution : ko.observable(),
    selectedLevel : ko.observable(),
    selectedFaculty : ko.observable()
};

viewModel.togaLevels = ko.computed(function(){
    if(viewModel.selectedInstitution()){
        console.log(buildData());
        var make = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.togaMakers,function(item){
            console.log(item.text,viewModel.selectedInstitution());
                return item.text===viewModel.selectedInstitution();          
        });
        return make.childOptions;
    } 
});

viewModel.togaFaculties = ko.computed(function(){
    if(viewModel.selectedLevel()){
        var type = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.togaLevels(),function(item){
            console.log(item.text,viewModel.selectedLevel());
                return item.text===viewModel.selectedLevel();
          console.log("Answer:" + item);
        });
        return type.childOptions;
    } 
});
ko.cleanNode(viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

**buildData()**

```
function buildData() {
  var dataContainer = ko.observableArray([]);

  getData().then(function(newData) {
    parsed = JSON.parse(newData);
    processed = processData(parsed);
    dataContainer(processed);
  });

  return dataContainer;
};
```

**staticBuildData**

```
function staticbuildData(){
    var uomBachelor = new cascadingOption({
        text: 'Bachelor Degree',
        childOptions : [
            new cascadingOption({
                text: 'Faculty of Enviroment'
            }),
            new cascadingOption({
                text: 'Faculty of Education'
            })
        ]
    });

    var uomMaster = new cascadingOption({
        text: 'Master Degree',
        childOptions : [
            new cascadingOption({
                text: 'Faculty of Law'
            }),
            new cascadingOption({
                text: 'Faculty of Dental & Surgery'
            })
        ]
    });

    var uom = new cascadingOption({
        text: 'University 1',
        childOptions : [uomBachelor, uomMaster]
    });

    var mdx = new cascadingOption({
        text: 'University 2',
        childOptions : [
            new cascadingOption({
                text:'Bachelor Degree',
                childOptions : [
                    {text: 'Q5'},
                    {text: 'Q7'}
                ]
            }),
            new cascadingOption({
                text:'Master Degree',
                childOptions : [
                    {text: 'A3'},
                    {text: 'A4'},
                    {text: 'A6'}
                ]
            })
        ]
    });
    return [uom, mdx];
}
```

Comment: Can i see your html, or a jsfiddle preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with async data. The `buildData` function will **first** return an empty observable array, and **then** add the data.

The `togaLevel` computed, however, will evaluate when:

- It's first instantiated
- `selectedLevel` changes
- `togaMakers` changes

This means that you'll get an error when `selectedLevel` is true, and `togaMakers` is still empty. The `computed` value will evaluate, it will try to find the first in an empty array (returning `null`), and then try to get `null.childOptions`.

A quick fix would be to change the `return` statement to:

```
return type ? type.childOptions : null;
```

This makes the computed handle empty arrays by returning `null`.

Comment: Thank you @user3297291 for clarifying and helping me understand the issue. I will research "Asynchronous Dependent Observables".